# compare classes types. filter only bird in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, class, types

I have a list of animals. I want to filter out all birds.  How can I do this in Kotlin. can I sort them out by class somehow?

Here in class Zoo i want to implement getBirdZoo(), but i dont have a idea. Can someone help please?

```
class Zoo (){
    val animallist:MutableList<Animal> = mutableListOf()

    fun addAnimal(animal: Animal){
        if (!animallist.contains(animal)) animallist.add(animal)
    }

    fun getTotalAdoptionMoney() :Double{
        return animallist.sumOf { it.all_partner.sumOf { it.price } }
    }

    fun getBirdsInZoo(){
    }

    
}
```

Comment: If `Bird` is a subclass of `Animal`, then `fun getBirdsInZoo(): List<Bird> = animallist.filterIsInstance()`.